# CUDA 6.5 and Jetson TK1

Tags: cuda, cross-compiling

I have CUDA 6.5 in my host machine. To do cross compilation for Jetson TK1, do I have to have CUDA 6.0 in the host machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have CUDA 6.0 installed on your jetson, then to do cross-compiling you need to have CUDA 6.0 (nvcc and libraries) installed on your host machine.  (You could *also* have CUDA 6.5 installed on the host machine, if desired, but your build environment for cross-compiling would need to use CUDA 6.0 tools and libraries.)

This [blog post](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/nvidia-nsight-eclipse-edition-for-jetson-tk1/) will be a useful read, I think.

Cross compiling means the target executable is built on the host machine, not on the target.  Therefore, the target executable must be compatible with (in particular with the libraries on) the target machine.  This compatibility is achieved by having the correct version of nvcc as well as the correct library versions (CUDA version and target OS) to link against, that match your target.

Note that it is possible to "remotely" build on the jetson directly, as mentioned in the blog post, which would alleviate this requirement.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1-development-pack-1_0 says it is CUDA 6.5 compatible.